# Beginner: Delete row from Table and Database PHP/HTML/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Complete newbie to PHP/MySQL and HTML so please bear with me if I dont explain myself properly. At present I have an order form which stores the order in my database and shows it on a table in my admin area. I would like to be able to delete the row from the table and my database when I have completed the order.

At present my code looks like this:

```
<?php
//87229feely.php
include('connection.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderform");
echo "<table border='1' >
<tr>
<th><u>ID</th>
<th><u>Date</th>
<th><u>Product</th>
<th><u>Product Comments</th>
<th><u>Name</th>
<th><u>Address</th>
<th><u>Age</th>
<th><u>Delivery</th>
<th><u>Delete</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['productcomments'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['delivery'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"deleterow.php?id=".$row['id']."\">delete</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

    <?php
//deleterow.php
    include('connection.php');
    $id = $_GET['id']; //this needs to be sanitized 
    if(!empty($id)){
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM orderform WHERE id=".$id.";");
    }
    header("Location: 87229feely.php");
    ?>
```

Any help? All greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it because you don't know how to DELETE records using MySql and PHP or that you don't know how to perform this after a certain UI action takes place?

Comment: I dont know how to delete

Comment: http://www.gieson.com/school/mysql/#delete

Comment: I would say google delete Mysql. is not that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not meet security standards but should do the job:

```
<?php
//index.php
include('connection.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderform");
echo "<table border='1' >
<tr>
<th><u>ID</th>
<th><u>Date</th>
<th><u>Product</th>
<th><u>Product Comments</th>
<th><u>Name</th>
<th><u>Address</th>
<th><u>Age</th>
<th><u>Delivery</th>
<th><u>Delete</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['productcomments'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['delivery'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\">delete</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

<?php
//delete.php
include('connection.php');
$id = $_GET['id']; //this needs to be sanitized 
if(!empty($id)){
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM orderform WHERE id=".$id.";");
}
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in /web/users/l1071039/bobbin/deleterow.php on line 4 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /web/users/l1071039/bobbin/connection.php:7) in /web/users/l1071039/bobbin/deleterow.php on line 8

Comment: Rows are deleting but its not sending me back to the 87229feely.php?

Comment: as it is now, 87229feely.php needs to be in the same folder as deleterow.php. Also make sure nothing is outputted (echo, print, errors,...) before you call the `header()`funtcion

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this. Since you're a beginner, this would probably be the most straight-forward (albeit not how I would do it)

1. Create a form around the table
2. Add a button on the `delete` column for each row and assign an `id` to it (the ID should be the ID from your database) `<input type="submit" name="submit" value"/*YOUR ID*/">`
3. Add some processing script before the table is being parsed

> ```
> if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
>     $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id='/*YOUR ID*/'";
>     mysql_query($sql);
> }
> ```

Comment: Also, when you're more advanced, use PDO or MySQLi instead of mysql queries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,you need to send ID of completed order to next form. You cam do this by adding:

```
echo("<input type='hidden' name='orderID' value='".$row['id']."'/>");
```

That will create a hidden field with value of ID.

If your form uses POST:

then:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$orderID = $_POST['orderID'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$oderID");
}
```

If you are using GET method:

```
<form method="GET">
```

You could either use hidden field as mentioned above or you could parse ID of order in GET url:

```
<form action='action.php?id=".$row['id']."'>
```

and after submitting:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['id')){
$orderID = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$orderID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this with PDO

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
?>
<form name="" action="delete.php" method="post"> 
    <table border='1' >
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th><u>ID</th>
            <th><u>Date</th>
            <th><u>Product</th>
            <th><u>Product Comments</th>
            <th><u>Name</th>
            <th><u>Address</th>
            <th><u>Age</th>
            <th><u>Delivery</th>
            <th><u>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?php

        try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

            $row = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM orderform');

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"id[]\" id=\"checkAll\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" /></td>" 
                echo "<td>" . $row['id']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['productcomments'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['delivery'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php

$id 
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {


    include('connection.php');

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

        $sql="DELETE FROM orderform WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$conn->quote($id)).")";
        $stmt->exec($sql);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```